# after the command "npm start" I do not see changes in the console, as if the code is not being updated on the fly. JS

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

after the command "npm start" I do not see changes in the console, as if the code is not being updated on the fly.

{
"scripts": {
"format": "prettier --write app",
"start": "http-server"
},
"dependencies": {
"http-server": "^14.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"prettier": "^2.0.5"
}
}

My version of node: 7.11.1

i have a macbook

What can I do ?

Thank you

Comment: What output do you expect `http-server` to create?

Answer (score 0):

Node do not automatically restart after changes :)

You should use eg. nodemon:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

```
npm i nodemon --dev
```

Then start your app like that:

```
nodemon index.js
```

Comment: I don't have index.js but game.js and quote.js, so what should I do? forgive me if I have a stupid question. I added a photo under the post ... if you could have a peek

Comment: you probably start your script like: "node [script_name].js", so instead try with "nodemon [script_name].js" :)

Comment: codesandbox.io/s/trusting-shamir-23pt2d?file=/src/Game.js I do this: nodemon Game.js, not node game.js   but it doesn't work ... will you look at the code please?

Answer (score 0):

donnot reload your page.
you can use eg. nodemon: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, but it still doesn't go ... I installed a nodemon.     {
"scripts": {
"format": "prettier --write app",
"start": "http-server"
},
"dependencies": {
"http-server": "^14.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"nodemon": "^2.0.16",
"prettier": "^2.0.5"
}
}

[image]

then I have to in the console:  nodemon game.js ?

Comment: Why do you use http-server to start? Try creating your custom http server instead :P

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).